# Armadillo Dot product C++

Tags: c++, product, armadillo, scalar

I am currently on Ubuntu code::blocks and run into a few problems when trying to do linear algebra.

under compiler settings>search directories>compiler i have "/usr/include"

and under compiler settings>search directories>linker i have "/user/lib"

my liblapack-dev, libblas-dev, libboost-dev, libarmadillo-dev are installed via apt-get

i commented which part of the code give me error. without the difficult part of the code my code runs fine, so i think i have armadillo installed fine? so why cant i access all its functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    mat A;
    A<<1<<2<<endr<<3<<4;
    cout<<A;
    vec e=A.col(0);
    vec r=A.col(1);
    cout<<endl<<e<<endl<<r<<endl;//works perfectly up to here
    //if only there was not more of these codes
    cout<<e*r<<endl;//doesnt work from here anymore
    float y=dot(A,A);//from here on i get the error message:
    cout<<y<<endl;//'wrapper_ddot_' is not defined
    double z=as_scalar(e*r);//and wrapper_blas.hpp file opens
    double t=dot(e,r);
    cout<<z<<endl;//and points me to line 185
    return 0;//with an error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the code. You are using `e*r` but they are both 2x1 so you need to transpose `e` as `e.t()*r` so you get a 1x1 product. You also have the same problem three rows below. If you installed Armadillo using `apt-get` there is normally no need to add the blas/lapack libs. It should be sufficient to use the `-larmadillo` flag to the linker.

Comment: ive just tried ur solution but it still didnt work giving me the same error :/. even when commenting out all others. ive seen on a couple tutorials though people use these functions without transpose. thanks though

Comment: actually which command do you give to the linker? i just seen some others use "g++ -O2 -o armadillo_example armadillo_example.cpp -larmadillo" to the linker but do you change directory intot he project files when doing so and use ur project to link to it every single time?

Comment: If you use code::blocks then you only need to add '-larmadillo' under 'Linker settings->Other linker options'. The command line example you mentioned should also work.

Comment: OMFG MAGIC IT WORKS! THANKS BRO!